# Migrate from Mediawiki to a Perl Wiki

Tags: perl, wiki, mediawiki, catalyst

Do you know a automated way to easily migrate the database of a *Wikimedia* Wiki to *Mojomojo* or another **Perl Wiki** ?

Comment: Yes: setup the new wiki and copy and paste all articles from the old to the new one, correcting the wiki-syntax if needed ;)

Comment: Find the documentation for the target wiki and find out if there is a migration strategy?

Comment: @CanSpice: well, that would answer his question directly without a nice post on stackoverflow. I don't think that's a good answer ;)

Comment: @Erik: I mean, an _automated_ way, sorry, I would like to avoid to copy and paste every pages, and it would be pretty to keep history, diffs, users, etc.

Comment: /usr/bin/perl migrate_wiki.pl -oldtype=mediawiki -oldhost=<old database host> -newtype=mojomojo -newhost=<new database host>

Comment: @Erik: I would like to do this trick if nothing exists, but I was asking if somebody would know the trick before I try from scratch :)

Comment: @Sebf - stackoverflow isn't the platform for "avoid to read the documentation and finding someone that did" - as CanSpice said: Find the documentation for the target wiki and find out if there is a migration strategy - it's not up to the community to do your homework.

Comment: @Erik: I guess why do you think that I don't read the targets's documentations before ? I was asking _after_ searching, and _because_ I've searched :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't know of any pre-built automated way to do that. I would imagine that if the wiki is very large then it might be worth rolling your own however--  in which case I'd start by [comparing the two](http://www.wikimatrix.org/compare/MediaWiki+MojoMojo). Since they both use a database backend I'd probably look at pulling the data straight out of the one database, munging the format, and inserting it into the target database.

Comment: Use the MediaWiki API for export instead, it papers over a lot of the oddities in the schema/data; raw db access is almost never useful.